# How do I use sensor batching in android

Tags: android, batch-processing, android-sensors

My mSensorManager set the maxReportLatencyUs to 1 minute. Hope to batch the step counter events to be reported roughly every 1 minute. However, the onSensorChanged event still report every time a step occur.

So my question is how to use the feature of batch event process (maxReportLatencyUs)

This question is related to 
[Android - How I receive sensors data in batching mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998355/android-how-i-receive-sensors-data-in-batching-mode)

Thanks very much

Comment: have you figured it out by now? I am basically facing the exact same problem.